# communication betwen NRF52840 and Android

Tags: android, nrf52

I am working on nRF52840, nRF5_SDK_15.2.0, pca10056,usbd_cdc_acm

I can now communicate nrf52840 with PC,However, I failed to connect nrf52840 to android,Android recognizes the device,But we can't communicate

Can we communicate with android normally or need some special Settings .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can communicate with Android devices using the nRF52840. There is an android project that works out of the box. Specifically, I tested this app using the same SDK version (v15.2.0).

https://github.com/NordicPlayground/Android-nRF-UART

You can test the app by flashing the SDK example from [SDK]/examples/ble_peripheral/ble_app_uart